# From Microsoft PowerBI Embedded using Flask application, how I can use url-filtering?

Tags: flask, url, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to have the flask application to have embedded PowerBI report for my organization.
I want it to return the URL based on the slicers and report page the users select, so people can copy the URL share it with others so users can easily share the report with their selection or even have that link hyperlinked. Is there a way for me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the report you want to share, adjust the slicers, spotlight some visual if you want, etc. and then click `Chat in Teams` button:

[image]

This will open a window to search for a team or channel. Copy the URL bellow the search box and send it to the other user:

[image]

Of course, the other user must have rights to see this report.